# 'This' is undefined in chrome dev tools when inside a async function since Angular 16

Tags: angular, typescript

Since we moved to Angular 16 we can't access this in the chrome dev tools but instead we have to use _this. This only happen in async function but why ? We didn't have to before. i've seen no change related in the changelog. Can someone explain ?

[image]

[image]

Angular 16
Node v18.17.0

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit` is an Angular event hook, it's never meant to have a `async` added to it, also it does not have a return  also so it should be:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.test); 
    const value = this.someAsyncFunc();
    console.log(value);
}

async someAsyncFunc(): string {
    return await this.resolveAfter2Seconds();
}

resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Hello, it is not recommended but it would work anyway. We can call promise in the ngonInit but in that case i don't know why i lose the context

Comment: @FriedrichDylan Could you replicate it on a stackblitz? [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tmhrsk?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Tried to replicate my issue on stackblitz but with no success https://stackblitz-starters-pf7bsw.stackblitz.io. In Stackblitz i have the wanted behavior, When debugging from browser console, this is never undefined in async function, in my local project, this context is under _this

Comment: @FriedrichDylan Check the `tsconfig.json` maybe its a configuration of which version of javascript to use! `es6`, `es2022`, `esNext` etc